# Tuleap and openresty configuration

Tags: tuleap

I am running tuleap using the default installation guidelines and everything is working fine. I was wondering is there anything specific which has to be done in order to replace nginx with openresty (enabling Lua support) and still keeping tuleap working.

Do I only need to move the nginx conf file to openresty conf?

Has someone done that already?